# Cosets of a Group and Bijection between $gH$ and $Hg$

Tags: group-theory

In my algebra book i read the following statement: Given the group $G$ and a subgroup $H$, for all $x\in G$ and all $g\in G$, $x\in gH \Leftrightarrow x^{-1}\in Hg$. The map $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ is a bijection between $gH$ and $Hg.$

What i cant understand is only the first statement. Let $x=gh$ for some $h\in H.$ It follows: $x^{-1}=h^{-1}g^{-1}$ and thus $x^{-1}\in Hg^{-1}.$ The only thing to suggest is the eventuality of the following $Hg^{-1}=Hg.$ But if the last equation were true, then it must follow $H=Hg^2,$ which for arbitrary $g\in G$ does not seem to be true.

My question is: Is the first statement in the book ($x\in gH \Leftrightarrow x^{-1}\in Hg$) a typo, or am i missing something here ? If it is a typo, does it have a consequence on the statement of the obvious bijection ?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it must be a typo. You aren't missing anything.

Comment: in the other hand $gh\mapsto hg$ bijects

Comment: The bijection between left and right cosets is $gH\mapsto Hg^{-1}.$

Comment: It is $ x\in gH \Leftrightarrow x^{-1}\in Hg^{-1}$ in the book; perhaps the $-1$ got lost in your notes? Do you have a scan from the book?

Comment: Many thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easy (but somewhat contrived) counterexample. Let $H$ be the trivial subgroup $H=\{1\}$. Then $x\in gH$ if and only if $x=g$. So the statement only holds in this case if $x=x^{-1}$, i.e. $x$ is of order $2$.